# Как вызвать ошибку 500?

Tags: apache, логирование

Перенастроил логи апача, нужно потестировать. Что написать в php-файле что бы сервер выбросил 500 ошибку? В случае каких-то простых опечаток в файле получаю Parse error: syntax error а это не то.

Comment: И в access.log при этом нету 500-го кода ответа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в .htaccess не поддерживаемые директивы.

Answer (score 1):

Суньте любую ерунду в htaccess и все.